# Python, Use a string argument to point to defined list/array object

Tags: python, string, object, arguments, call

Is it possible in python to have a string argument point to a defined object in the script?

For example, Lets say our argument is *-layers* and I have a list called *convloop* defined in the script as

```
convloop = ['conv2/3x3', 'conv2/3x3_reduce', 'conv2/3x3']
```

and i pass 'python example.py -layers convloop'

I need it to take that arg string(*convloop*) and point to the actual convloop list(array) not just the string '*convloop*'

I know i can do

```
if args.layers == 'convloop':
    #loop over layers as set in convloop array
    endparam = convloop[frame_i % len(convloop)]
```

And that will call the list(array) 'convloop' if the argstring is 'convloop'
and cycle through the list

However I have multiple lists in my script, and instead of rewritting this code each time for each list I want it to read the argstring and point to the matching list object so i can pass for example:

'`python example.py -layers pooploop`' and '`python example.py`' -layers fartloop' and have them point to the pooploop and fartloop lists accordingly

I am using python 2.7 btw

Comment: Why not just use a dictionary of arrays? Then you can do `my_loop = loop_for[args.layers]`.

Comment: Keep your data out of your variable names. If you want to do stuff like this, you should put your lists into a dict, using the desired list name as its key.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`globals()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#globals) or [`locals()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#locals) to get the corresponding object:

```
>>> oneloop = [1,2,3]
>>> globals()["oneloop"]
[1, 2, 3]
```

You probably shouldn't, though : it could be dangerous. It's also an indication that you should rethink the architecture of your script.

A dict would be a better idea:

```
>>> possible_loops = {"oneloop": [1,2,3], "twoloop": [4,5,6]}
>>> possible_loops
{'oneloop': [1, 2, 3], 'twoloop': [4, 5, 6]}
>>> possible_loops['oneloop']
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Or [`locals()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#locals) if you want to access local variables of a function.

Comment: Thank you so much! A dictionary was the way to go for my script!